# What is difference between declaring local variable at the time of definition and after definition?

Tags: java, local-variables, java-compiler-api

What is the difference between

```
public static void main(String [] ar){
    int var= 10;
    System.out.println(var);
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String [] ar){
    int var;
    var= 10;
    System.out.println(var);
}
```

moreover, what it reflects in Compiler/JVM?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference, except the number of lines you used.  It is a matter of style and for such simple case I would use the first example.

If the code were optimized to native code, the variable `var` might disappear entirely.

Comment: Agree with you when we are talking about how the code will behave (there is no difference in working). But I am Interested in replication of the code in Compiler and/or JVM.. eg: when the variable will be assigned it's value? at compile time or run time?

Comment: @Suraj assignment is performed at runtime.  The only thing the compiler does is inlining of constants known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you peter. I had missconseption that, in first case variable will be assigned it's value at compile time and in second case at runtime...

Comment: @Suraj the compile does very little except a) validate the source code, b) generate byte code.

Answer (score 0):

int var; //reserves the memory location for an int data type named var

var = 10 //assigns the integer 10 to the above location

You can do these separately or in one step as you demonstrated. There is no difference to the compiler.

Your syntax in the first example does both steps at the same time, whereas your second example separates the steps.

Answer (score -1):

```
    There is no at all difference between in both of the snippets mentioned other than number of lines taken to do declaration & initialization.
    The compiler will treat both of the things in the same fashion.
    Since initialization is been done before using the local variable in both the cases, there are no chances of error like 'Variable Not Initialized' or so.
```

Comment: Code is perfect within itself. There is no any error in both cases. I am specifically interested in the difference between compiler and JVM's work in the same (which I think there is).